# How to retain scroll position in Angular lists?

Tags: angular

So I am on my second Angular project which consists of a long list view and a detail view. (Thinking of the hero list example by official tutorial).

Every time I scroll down to the list and open a detail view and click "Back" from the detail view the list get reloaded and thus the scroll position get lost which means I need to scroll all the way down again.

Is there any way that I could retain the scroll position on previous view?

Thanks

Comment: Just save it to a shared service that is kept alive during such navigations and then set it the the previously saved position. There is currently no special support from Angular2.

Comment: sounds like a promising plan for me, but will wait for some more well-supported answer still. Thanks

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10929. This might also be interesting https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7791

Comment: This is frustrating. The only easy way I can see is using the [hidden] property but this means everything is in the same route. Did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could see is using z-index. Make two separate divs for your list and details. When you go to details, hide list view using z-index and when you come back to list view reset z-index. That way you won't loose scroll position.